# Identity based Authentication with Custom model

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add authentication to a asp net core 3.1 app.
I have a existing database which I generated the models from there. The main limitation is that I'm tied to the database structure.

For example this is the model that I need for users.

```
 public partial class TFactoryWorker: IdentityUser
    {
        public int idPerson { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int Token { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is the following, inherit the model from **IdentityUser** (I already have username, email, etc in that model) update the DBContext and customize the register / login fields in the scaffolded views. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

For example I need the FactoryWorker to login with a **Token** and **Code** instead of **email** and **password**

Is this a feasible way of doing this?

I also found this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1 . Here it defines a Contact Model with an **OwnerId** that relates to **AspNetUsers** table, so the original entity (*FactoryWorker*) requires a minimum change (*just add the OwnerId that binds to aspNetUser*)
The important point here, is that I need to add authentication without modifying the existing tables.
Any suggestions on how to proceed or some tips (I'm a beginner in all these stuff and I'm pretty overwhelmed by the amount of information... thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following.

I created an **asp net core app** with **individual user accounts**, and made the required changes to show a **Username** field instead of the default Email input field. *(This is just customizing the input model and templates from scaffolded items, the user now logs in with a username + password)*

**Then in my database I made some changes.**

In my **TFactoryWorker** Table I set the **Code** field to be the Primary key (This is a unique value and cannot be repeated). Remember the model below

```
 public partial class TFactoryWorker
    {
        public int idWorker {get;}
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int Token { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have AspNetUsers table with its proper fields (id, UserName, email, etc) (this is automatically generated through *migrations*), and I added to this table a Foreign key from field **UserName** to the table TFactoryWorker **Code**. **Code** is the same as **UserName**.

This way I do not have to modify my existing database. Probably some normalization to remove some redundant fields from the TFactoryWorker table *(This table contains an email, phone and some other fields that are already present in the AspNetUsers)*

The downside is that I need to make every user register again in the system but with their UserNames or Codes they were using in the previous application. Once they register in the app, the username from aspNetUsers is the same as the existing value in code in TFactoryWorker.

**Summarizing**

I use the default authentication and add a foreign key so I do not need to make changes in the rest of the tables, TFactoryWorker is just some additional data to AspNetUsers table, and they are binded by the foreign key, so If I need to get some information from an user, I'm able to get it by doing some joins.

I'm not sure if it's the right way, but it's working for me.